# not be able to commit and push a project to GitHub

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I already have a project on GitHub and I'm able to clone and got the files as I wanted.

I'm using clone from

[image: Clone worked]

Got the files and the .git folder

[image: Get worked]

But when I push back by clicking the check mark (commit) nothing happens

[image: Push NOT WORKING]

I usually upload files manually to GitHub website but my project is getting bigger, so..

Did I miss something about commit and push to GitHub??

Comment: for pushing the chnages to github using git there is a sequence of actions .i.e stage changes, commit and then push. Are you doing these in vscode?

Comment: it finally worked, thank you a lot. I need to add those changes to actually stage changes, then go on

Answer (score 2):

Using git through a GUI usually adds confusion instead of being helpful. One should try to get the git basics right in the first place.

A normal routine should be the following:

```
1. Clone project
2. Checkout a working branch
3. Make changes
4. Commit changes
5. Push changes
```

This routine is usually expanded and is cyclic like so:

```
1. Clone project
# for each new activity
  2. Checkout a working branch
  # each day
    2b. Git fetch          // will get new content from remote, updates you on what your colleagues are doing         
    3. Make changes
    4. Commit changes
    5. Push changes
```

It appears in your case you didn't do at least one of these steps.

Please note that *"uploading manually files on GitHub"* is jargon for: *"create new commit with a specified commit message and the files added to the staging area via GitHub GUI, sign off the commit with the GitHub user name and email"*.

This is important, since on your local machine you'll have to `git pull`, otherwise you'll be creating commits on a diverging history.

This should be an explanation on "what to do" and "how you get in your situation in the first place". It is probably out of scope to add more details in this answer, but please do let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to to Settings -> Extensions -> Git -> Post Commit Command, and choose "push" from the dropdown.

Only then clicking the tick (commit) will trigger a push automatically.

By default, committing would remain a local operation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, to have an overview of the changes you've made this command:

```
git status
```

is pretty useful and clean

And:

```
git log
```

to see the last commits made by you or other people

And then to add the files, and commit

```
git add [FILES]
git commit -m "Message.."
git pull
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use terminal/gitbash .

Here command .

check your status - if you have any changes you see here

```
git status

git add .                  // for adding changes data to git
git commit -m "commit here"
git pull                // check first you have any updated or not.
git push origin master // master replace your branch name
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using VS Code to clone and commit changes. I followed the below process and this works for me.

1. Cloned project (CTRL+SHIFT + P) -> git clone and gave git repo URL
2. Updated a file in the git repo
3. Selected the Source Control icon to look for the changes in current repo
4. Clicked on modified file (it will be visible with yellow colored M letter)
5. There will be a plus mark, click that and stage the change
6. Staged changes will be shown at the top
7. Select the file and click on check mark to commit the changes and enter the commit message

Hopefully this works for you as well